# Regular expression for Url with multiple directory

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have to match a set of URLs which has 1 or more than one directory. Can anyone please help me with building the regular expression.

Below are the Urls for which I'm building a regex

```
1.  /p-b/foo-id/Sas-p
2.  /p-b/foo-id/cust-Sas-p
3.  /p-b/foo-id/Sas-p/Sas-value-p
4.  /p-b/foo-id/Sas-p/sm-deb-ad
5.  /p-b/foo-id/Sas-p/sm-deb-ex
6.  /p-b/foo-id/Sas-p/sm-deb-pl
7.  /p-b/foo-id/Sas-p/po-2-ch
8.  /p-b/foo-id/wm/5-y-6-p
9.  /p-b/foo-id/wm/5-y-6-p/eq
10. /p-b/foo-id/wm/5-y-6-p/dv
11. /p-b/foo-id/wm/5-y-6-p/cu
12. /p-b/foo-id/wm/5-y-6-p/m
13. /p-b/foo-id/wm/5-y-6-p/others
14. /p-b/foo-id/pgm/my-first-foo
15. /p-b/foo-id/pgm/foo-fa
16. /p-b/foo-id/pgm/foo-ho
17. /p-b/foo-id/pgm/foo-vi
18. /p-b/ni-b/ni-ps/Sas-p/seafearer-p
19. /p-b/foo-first/gs
```

I've built a regex which is working fine for the below URLs, However, I'm getting other URLs as well which I don't want to include.

The regex which I've built:

```
(/p-b/(foo-id|ni-b|foo-first/(Sas-p|cust-Sas-p|wm|pgm|ni-ps|gs/(Sas-value-p|sm-deb-ad|sm-deb-ex|sm-deb-pl|po-2-ch|5-y-6-p|my-first-foo|foo-fa|foo-ho|foo-vi|Sas-p/(eq|dv|cu|m|others|seafearer-p))))).*
```

Comment: What is the goal of your question? Do you also want to match 19?

Comment: i want to match only above 19 url's along with query param to those url if any, when i check my regex online and test, it seems correct, but the moment i add segment created with this regex to my google analytics report i am getting other url's as well.

Comment: I see a lot of `foo` Is `/p-b/` the only real directory? The you might use `^/p-b(?:/[^\n/]+)+` https://regex101.com/r/1ezN3l/1

Comment: Please note, that if you build a segment to include sessions/users having visited specific pages, you will see other pages in your reports, as the segment includes all page visits of these sessions/users.